# Display date by increasing 2 days from current date

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a shortcode to display the date by increasing 2 days from the current date. For example, if today is 16 may, I want to show 18 may by shortcode.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    if( !function_exists( 'yourFunction' ) ) {
        function yourFunction(){
            return  date('d-M', strtotime("+2 days"));
        }
        add_shortcode( 'Youuniqueshortcode', 'yourFunction' );
    }
?>
```

Hope this will Help You 
if not Let me know :)
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Hi PLease check below code

```
<?php
$date = strtotime("+2 day");
echo date('M d, Y', $date);
?>
```

I hope this will help you.